# How to sort specific values from an xml file

Tags: xml, sed, awk

I have an xml file as follows:

```
<Exchange DateTime="17/09/2010 18:00:00">
<Content Percent="0.20" Price="63.862" Sign="1"/>
<Content Percent="0.25" Price="80.989" Sign="1"/>
<Content Percent="0.07" Price="1.4970" Sign="1"/>
<Content Percent="-0.31" Price="1.9530" Sign="-1"/>
</Exchange>
```

There are 4 variables called A,B,C,D.

I need a script which outputs as follows:

```
Last update: 17/09/2010 18:00:00 
A: 63.862 (% 0.20) 
B: 80.989 (% 0.25)
C: 1.4970 (% 0.07) 
D: 1.9530 (% -0.31)
```

Is that possible? Well I really need that for my job :( Please help me, ppl. I will really appreciate your help!!

Comment: There's no way to add information that isn't present in the input so the currencies are going to be challenging. How do you derive the appropriate currency abbreviations to display?

Comment: From where those variables (IMKB, SD, USD, EUR) came from?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Last update: `grep -o 'DateTime="[^"]*"' $1 | sed -e 's/DateTime="\([^"]*\)"/\1/'`
grep -o 'Percent="[^"]*" Price="[^"]*"' $1 | 
       sed -e 's/Percent="\([^"]*\)" Price="\([^"]*\)"/: \2 (% \1)/'
```

This will display

```
Last update: 17/09/2010 18:00:00
: 63.862 (% 0.20)
: 80.989 (% 0.25)
: 1.4970 (% 0.07)
: 1.9530 (% -0.31)
```

Didn't know what IMKB, USD and EUR means, if they are based on Percent then you can use this

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Last update: `grep -o 'DateTime="[^"]*"' $1 | sed -e 's/DateTime="\([^"]*\)"/\1/'`
grep -o 'Percent="[^"]*" Price="[^"]*"' $1 | 
       sed -e 's/Percent="\([^"]*\)" Price="\([^"]*\)"/: \2 (% \1)/' |
       sed -e 's/\(.*(% 0.20)\)/IMKB: \1/' | 
       sed -e 's/\(.*(% 0.07)\)/USD: \1/' |
       sed -e 's/\(.*(% -0.31)\)/EUR: \1/'
```

Above will display

```
Last update: 17/09/2010 18:00:00
IMKB: : 63.862 (% 0.20)
: 80.989 (% 0.25)
USD: : 1.4970 (% 0.07)
EUR: : 1.9530 (% -0.31)
```

I didn't know sed very well so mayby there is simple and shorter solusion using only sed.

**Update**
This is shorter version

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Last update: `grep -o 'DateTime="[^"]*"' $1 | sed -e 's/DateTime="\([^"]*\)"/\1/'`
grep -o 'Percent="[^"]*" Price="[^"]*"' $1 | sed -e 's/Percent="\([^"]*\)" Price="\([^"]*\)"/: \2 (% \1)/' -e 's/\(.*(% 0.20)\)/IMKB\1/' -e 's/\(.*(% 0.07)\)/USD\1/' -e 's/\(.*(% -0.31)\)/EUR\1/' -e 's/\(.*(% 0.25)\)/SD\1/'
```

```
Last update: 17/09/2010 18:00:00
IMKB: 63.862 (% 0.20)
SD: 80.989 (% 0.25)
USD: 1.4970 (% 0.07)
EUR: 1.9530 (% -0.31)
```

Comment: Well, those percentiles are not static so I can not use your 2nd solution. There are 4 variables called IMKB, SD, USD, EUR and I want them to be displayed in the beginning of the lines. Well, thank you, though. It is really much better than nothing, my friend.

Answer (score 0):

http://cnnturk.com/finans/ticker/endeks.asp is where I get the XML file but it does NOT have newlines so I am not able to use your solution while using curl :(

My purpose is to come up with a shell script which gathers data from the address mentioned above and then displays information about both prices and price changes of stock exchange index, gold, usd, and euro.

I need to use curl, awk, sed, and grep to accomplish this but I can't figure out how because it requires complex use of shell programming skills.

Answer (score -1):

hope this helps.
Even i am a newbie in Perl.just tried my luck.

```
open CONFIG,"example.dat";
    while(<CONFIG>)
    {
    if($.==1)
    {
     s/.*\"(\d+\/\d+\/\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+)\".*$/Last update: $1/g;
    }
    if($.==2)
    {
    s/.*\"(-?\d+\.?\d+).*\"(\d+\.?\d+)\".*$/A: $2 (% $1)/g;
    }
    if($.==3)
    {
    s/.*\"(-?\d+\.?\d+).*\"(\d+\.?\d+)\".*$/B: $2 (% $1)/g;
    }
    if($.==4)
    {
    s/.*\"(-?\d+\.?\d+).*\"(\d+\.?\d+)\".*$/C: $2 (% $1)/g;
    }
    if($.==5)
    {
    s/.*\"(-?\d+\.?\d+).*\"(\d+\.?\d+)\".*$/D: $2 (% $1)/g;
    }
    s/<\/exchange>//i;
    print ;
    }


close CONFIG;
```